# SPARQL get more than one subitem

Tags: api, sparql

I query an API with a simple SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX ...
SELECT DISTINCT *
    WHERE {
    ?item dct:date ?date .
    ?item dct:title ?title .
    ?item rdfs:info ?info .
    }
```

And this returns me an xml

```
<results>
    <result>
        <binding name='title'>
            <literal>titletitle</literal>
        </binding>
        <binding name='info'>
            <uri>link</uri>
        </binding>
        <binding name='date'>
            <literal datatype='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime'>2012-12-21T02:26:00+00:00</literal>
        </binding>
        <binding name='item'>
            <uri>link</uri>
        </binding>
    </result>
    ...
</results>
```

But the problem is: I know, that there are more than one links of rdfs:info matched to this item. How can I query such that I get

```
...
<binding name='info'>
    <uri>link1</uri>
</binding>
<binding name='info'>
    <uri>link2</uri>
</binding>
<binding name='info'>
    <uri>link3</uri>
</binding>
...
```

? Is this simple, or do I need a subquery or some strange `UNION`?
If I just try

```
    PREFIX ...
SELECT DISTINCT *
    WHERE {
    ?item dct:date ?date .
    ?item dct:title ?title .
    OPTIONAL (?item rdfs:info ?info1 ).
    OPTIONAL (?item rdfs:info ?info2 ).
    }
```

that would return all possible permutations of the values of `?info1` and `?info2`. Plus, I don't know the number of info items.

If I add `FILTER (?info1 != ?info2)`, I still get some permutations. I think from an algebraic point of view it would be possible to `FILTER (?info1 < ?info2)`, to discard permutations. But how can I apply `<` on uris?

Comment: I posted this on http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/20424/sparql-get-more-than-one-subitem and voted this for closing, since after one hour there are only 7 views. This seems to be off topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, I'm afraid. The results of a `SELECT` (or, in fact, any `WHERE`) are tabular, and you can't have nested tables (as found in some relational databases) or any other suitable structure.

The straightforward option is add an `ORDER BY ?item` to your existing query. That will keep everything together at least, so you can process item by item. In the past I've written wrappers to iterate over relational data like this, allowing something like:

```
foreach (item: iterateOverBy(results, "item")
    foreach (date: iterateOverBy(results, "date")
        foreach (title: iterateOverBy(results, "title")
            foreach (info: iterateOverBy(results, "info")
                ...do something...
```

But SPARQL can return RDF, of course, so you could use:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?item dct:date ?date ; dct:title ?title ; rdfs:info ?info }
WHERE ...
```

Internally that will do the same work, but the result won't contain lots of repetition like the `SELECT` will.

My final suggestion isn't appropriate to the problem as given, but I ought to mention it.

So far the actual query processing hasn't really changed, just the form of the results. But suppose the query where of the form:

```
WHERE {
  ...some condition to select items...
  ?item dct:date ?date .
  ?item ... as before ...
}
```

The condition might be `FILTER (?date > ...something...)` or `?item rdf:type ex:InterestingItem`, or whatever.

In this case you might consider `DESCRIBE`:

```
DESCRIBE ?item WHERE { ...some condition to select items... }
```

That will return (in rdf) information about the items that match that condition. Here the query just picks out the items, not the things we want to know about them.